# Preserve old data in browser's local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I want to preserve my data when the the button is clicked. In this code, the current data is successfully stored in `localStorage`, but when the next update arrives, local storage is updated. I want to store both pieces of data without overwriting anything.

```js
handleSubmit = (e,props) => {
      let localStorageArray = [];
      let myObj = {name : this.props.UserName,
                   Email : this.props.email,
                   Password : this.props.password,
                  Phone : this.props.phone};
      e.preventDefault();
      let key = 'Item 1';
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(myObj));
      this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
          change={...values}; 
          this.props.changeState(change);
        }
      });
    };
```

Comment: You can use a different key but ,Can you describe the purpose of storing both old and new data?

Comment: This is because you are using the same key to `setItem` in localStorage.

Comment: agent_hunt the purpose of storing both data is to create a login and sign up page. so i preserve all user signup data to the local storage and then use it to login page

Comment: May be I am diverging.  Local storage is for offline storage. Typical signup , login workflow stores information in memory and happens mostly in one step. If backend supports, you should be able to login automatically as part of signup as well.

Comment: thanks for your advice @agent_hunt, but I do this for a study purpose so I learn this how to store data to the local storage. please, you have any solution then please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

You should get what's in your storage at first, before updating it.

Declare `key` at start, then declare `localStorageArray` by affecting it your current storage value:

```
handleSubmit = (e,props) => {
      let key = 'Item 1';
      // Retrieves your storage, or initializes it with an empty array if nothing is found.
      let localStorageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key) || '[]');
      let myObj = {name : this.props.UserName,
                   Email : this.props.email,
                   Password : this.props.password,
                  Phone : this.props.phone};

      e.preventDefault();

      // Pushes your new object.
      localStorageArray.push(myObj);

      // Updates your storage.
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(localStorageArray));

      this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
          change={...values}; 
          this.props.changeState(change);
        }
      });
    };
```

Below is a working example:

```js
// As the document is sandboxed, the following is to simulate the "localStorage".
const CustomStorage = { data: {} };

CustomStorage.getItem = (key) => CustomStorage.data[key];
CustomStorage.setItem = (key, value) => (CustomStorage.data[key] = value);
// ----------

const eAddBtn = document.querySelector('#btn-add'),
  eLogBtn = document.querySelector('#btn-log');
  
// logs the storage's data.
eLogBtn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(JSON.parse(CustomStorage.getItem('_key') || '[]')));
  
// Adds an entry into the storage.
eAddBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const eInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input'),
    storageKey = '_key',
    storageItem = JSON.parse(CustomStorage.getItem(storageKey) || '[]'),
    obj = {};
    
  Array.from(eInputs).forEach(eInput =>  obj[eInput.id] = eInput.value);
  
  storageItem.push(obj);
  
  CustomStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(storageItem));
});
```

```html
<label for="name">
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="name">
</label>

<label for="age">
  <input id="age" type="number" min="0" placeholder="age">
</label>

<button id="btn-add">Add to storage</button>
<button id="btn-log">Log the storage</button>
```

Comment: **TypeError: localStorageArray.push is not a function
RegistrationForm.handleSubmit**                                                                                 this  type of error shows

Comment: You have this error because the original content of `Item 1` item of your storage is not an array. Try again by emptying your local storage before testing this.

Comment: I corrected the line `let localStorageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key) || '[]');` that was wrong. Maybe that was the cause. But my previous comment still need to be done. I also added a small live example.